# How do I get the screen to erase then draw something new in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a code that uses python and pygame that when certain conditions are met its supposed to erase the screen and print the words "GAME OVER" in the middle. But when the conditions are met the piece that collides with the player just passes right through and does not do anything. How do I make it so the screen erases and the words print?

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
pygame.init()
size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodger")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bullet_x = 350
bullet_y = 0

bullet_x2 = 175
bullet_y2 = 0

bullet_x3 = 525
bullet_y3 = 0

circle_x = 350
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            circle_x += 5
    bullet_y += 1
    bullet_y2 += 2
    bullet_y3 += 3
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (circle_x,600), 15)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bullet_x, bullet_y), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bullet_x2, bullet_y2), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bullet_x3, bullet_y3), 20)
    if bullet_y == 800:
        bullet_y = 0
        bullet_x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bullet_y2 == 800:
        bullet_y2 = 0
        bullet_x2 = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bullet_y3 == 800:
        bullet_y3 = 0
        bullet_x3 = random.randint(20, 680)
    if circle_x == 685:
        circle_x = 15
    if bullet_y == 600 and bullet_x == circle_x or bullet_y2 == 600 and bullet_x2 == circle_x or bullet_y3 == 600 and bullet_x3 == circle_x:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',40,True,False)
        text = font.render("GAME OVER",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text,[0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(300)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable circle_y and set it to 600 (circle_y = 600), right below circle_x = 350.
Then change line 50 to:

```
if (abs(bullet_y - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x - circle_x) < 35) or (abs(bullet_y2 - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x2 - circle_x) < 35) or abs(bullet_y3 - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x3 - circle_x) < 35:
```

This will fix your collision problem. May I suggest you refactor the exepression to

```
do_circle_and_bullet_hit = abs(bullet_y - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x - circle_x) < 35
do_circle_and_bullet2_hit = abs(bullet_y2 - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x2 - circle_x) < 35
do_circle_and_bullet3_hit = abs(bullet_y3 - circle_y) < 35 and abs(bullet_x3 - circle_x) < 35
if do_circle_and_bullet_hit or do_circle_and_bullet2_hit or do_circle_and_bullet3_hit:
```

The idea is to check the distance between the circle and each of the bullets. If the distance is below 35 they hit.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help to create a [Pygame Rect Class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.htm) to test for collisions. They are made by doing `bulletrect = pygame.rect.Rect(xpos, ypos, xsize, ysize)`. Later in the code, you can do `bulletrect.y +=` 1, 2, or 3 to make it go down. Doing `bulletrect.x =` or `bulletrect.y =` will change the x and y position of the circles. To show the circles on the screen, change `pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bullet_x, bullet_y), 20)` or any other circle to `pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, bulletrect.center, 20)`. To actually check for collisions, use the colliderect method: `playerrect.colliderect(bulletrect)`.
The code would be:

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
pygame.init()
size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodger")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bulletrect1 = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 0, 20, 20))
bulletrect2 = pygame.rect.Rect((175, 0, 20, 20))
bulletrect3 = pygame.rect.Rect((525, 0, 20, 20))

circlerect = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 600, 20, 20))
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            circle.rect.x += 5
    bulletrect1.rect.y += 1
    bulletrect2.rect.y2 += 2
    bulletrect3.rect.y3 += 3
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (circlerect.center), 15)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect1.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect2.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect3.center), 20)
    if bulletrect1.y == 800:
        bulletrect1.y = 0
        bulletrect1.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bulletrect2.y == 800:
        bulletrect2.y = 0
        bulletrect2.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bulletrect3.y == 800:
        bulletrect3.y = 0
        bulletrect3.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if circlerect.x == 685:
        circlerect.x = 15
    if [bulletrect.colliderect(circlerect) for bulletrect in (bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3)]
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',40,True,False)
        text = font.render("GAME OVER",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text,[0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(300)
pygame.quit()
```

Another good place to learn about pygame and pygame rects is [Al Sweigarts free online book](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/) teaching python. [Chapter 2](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html) teaches rects.

EDIT:

The last code didn't really work so here is some new and improved code:

```
import pygame
import random
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
pygame.init()
size = (700,700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodger")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def resetpositions():
    global bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3, circlerect
    bulletrect1 = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect2 = pygame.rect.Rect((175, 0, 20, 20))
    bulletrect3 = pygame.rect.Rect((525, 0, 20, 20))

    circlerect = pygame.rect.Rect((350, 600, 20, 20))

resetpositions()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            circlerect.x += 5
    bulletrect1.y += 1
    bulletrect2.y += 2
    bulletrect3.y += 3
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (circlerect.center), 15)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect1.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect2.center), 20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (bulletrect3.center), 20)
    if bulletrect1.y == 800:
        bulletrect1.y = 0
        bulletrect1.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bulletrect2.y == 800:
        bulletrect2.y = 0
        bulletrect2.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if bulletrect3.y == 800:
        bulletrect3.y = 0
        bulletrect3.x = random.randint(20, 680)
    if circlerect.x == 685:
        circlerect.x = 15
    if circlerect.collidelist((bulletrect1, bulletrect2, bulletrect3)) == 0:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',40,True,False)
        text = font.render("GAME OVER",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text,[0,0])
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(3000)
        resetpositions()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(300)
```

I changed it so now it calls pygame.display.update() when it shows GAME OVER on the screen. It will also wait three seconds so the GAME OVER doesn't immediately go away. Also, it actually works now. Visit the two websites to get a clear understanding of what pygame.rect.Rect is used for. It helps a lot.

Comment: The code does not work yet, I'm still trying to fix it. Go to the websites because pygame.rect was pretty much made for collisions.

Comment: Thank you for your help in solving this problem